# How to read a line of numbers and display the sum?

Tags: java

I'm working on a program that will read a whole line of numbers and then it will display the sum. It must be written in java and it must be as simple as possible. So nothing to much harder than some arrays or what ever needed to just make it work.

This is an example of what I want:

```
Please enter some numbers with a space In between each.
12 34 7 93 4
This is the Sum of those numbers: 150
```

I have had a number of attempts and this is what I have got at the moment.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numbers;
    int total;                  
    System.out.println("Please enter some numbers with a space between each");
    numbers = kb.nextInt();
    for(int i=args.length; i<numbers; i++) {
        System.out.println("The sum is " + numbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: *I want a program that foo the bar*... ok, starting working on it, nothing stops you. If you have a problem, please post it here in form of question. We **do not** write free code for you.

Comment: Ok sorry about that.  I have had a number of attempts at it but now I am completely stuck.  This is what I have got but It down;t work like what I want.

Comment: Ok, good to know you did something. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26695414/edit) your question and provide your attempts, then we can help you to solve your specific problem.

Comment: Yea. Okay sorry just doing that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Scanner#nextInt` just reads a single `int` from the input stream. Instead, you want to read a bunch of numbers and start working on them.

I can think on two solutions for this:

1. Read the whole line (using `Scanner#nextLine`), split it by blank space (`" "`) (using `String#split`), convert each `String` into an `int` and calculate the sum (using `Integer#parseInt`).

   ```
   int total = 0;
   System.out.println("Please enter some numbers with a space between each");
   String lineWithNumbers = kb.nexLine();
   String[] numbers = lineWithNumbers.split(" ");
   for (String number : numbers) {
       total += Integer.parseInt(number);
   }
   ```
2. Read the whole line (using `Scanner#nextLine`), use another `Scanner` to read the integers stored in this `String` and calculate the sum.

   ```
   int total = 0;
   System.out.println("Please enter some numbers with a space between each");
   String lineWithNumbers = kb.nexLine();
   Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(lineWithNumbers);
   while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
       total += lineScanner.nextInt();
   }
   ```

Comment: I have changed the nextInt to nextLine.  Since I did that do I need to change my two Int's to Strings

Comment: @BenjaminMcIntyre yes, you will need other variables as well. Have you worked with arrays before? Otherwise I would need to provide another solution.

Comment: No I have not worked with arrays.  However I will need to know them and I would be happy to use them if that is the way to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much for that.  I have spent hours working on it but I have just not been able to get it to work.  I am now going to learn arrays and see if that will help me when doing programs like this. Thanks very much.

Comment: Oh Just one more question.  Would it be hard to make it so as it does the same thing but when you enter your numbers, lets say you put a word in there too. The program would just skip the word and leave it out and just display the sum for the numbers

Comment: Using approach 1, you should check if the `String` can be converted into an `int` by using a `try/catch` statement around it. With approach 2, this is already covered.

Comment: Sorry I down really know what you mean.  I tried this:  try {
  } catch (int) {
  }                                                                                            Is that what you meant?

Comment: @BenjaminMcIntyre start reading here: [The Java Tutorials: The try block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)